# Why isn't antlr 4 breaking my tokens up as expected?

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4

So I am fairly new to ANTLR 4.  I have stripped down the grammar as much as I can to show the problem:

```
grammar DumbGrammar;

equation
   : expression (AND expression)*
   ;

expression
   : ID
   ;


ID : LETTER(LETTER|DIGIT)* ;

AND: 'and';

LETTER: [a-zA-Z_];
DIGIT    : [0-9];
WS : [ \r\n\t] + -> channel (HIDDEN);
```

If use this grammar, and use the sample text: `abc and d` I get a weird tree with unexpected structure as shown below(using IntelliJ and ANTLR4 plug in):

[image]

If I simply change the terminal rule `AND: 'and';` to read `AND: '&&';` and then submit `abc && d` as input I get the following tree, as expected:

[image]

I cannot figure out why it isn't parsing `"and"` correctly, but does parse `'&&'` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The input `"and"` is being tokenized as an `ID` token. Since both `ID` and `AND` match the input `"and"`, ANTLR needs to make a decision which token to choose. It takes `ID` since it was defined before `AND`.

The solution: define `AND` before `ID`:

```
AND: 'and';

ID : LETTER(LETTER|DIGIT)* ;
```

Comment: Wow! Painfully obvious! Thanks!! :)

Comment: check if ID == 'andy' will work, i guess not. You have to include 'and' token into ID rule so as id's containing 'and' substring will work as well

Comment: So this is the correct answer, why not upvote and accept @shuri17 ?

Comment: @Divisadero the input `"andy"` will be tokenized as an `ID`, as expected.

Comment: @BartKiers yeah, you are right. I forgot it can be a problem only if ID will be parser rule => id